# HikariCP statement caching on MS SQL (microsoft JDBC driver 4.1)

Tags: java, connection-pooling, mssql-jdbc, hikaricp

How can I enable statement caching in MS SQL RDBMS for HikariCP connection pool ?

For MySQL it is via :

```
dataSource.cachePrepStmts=true
dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize=250
dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048
```

For PostgreSQL via:

```
hikari.dataSource.prepareThreshold=1
```

For Oracle, the following works:

```
dataSource.implicitCachingEnabled=true
and adjusting via  setMaxStatements() method of OracleDataSource
```

But I have not found anything for MS SQL 2012 and up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Statement caching has to be provided by the database driver, HikariCP does not provide any statement caching. And as far as I can see (*), neither does the "Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server". This leaves the option to use the alternative database driver jTDS. The [jTDS home page](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) does not indicate compatability with MS SQL 2012 but, the [sourceforge project page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/) does (I have not used jTDS so I am assuming the project page is more up to date (**)).

By default the jTDS driver caches 500 statements per connection (see the comments about `maxStatements` on the [FAQ page](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html)).

Instead of using the `dataSourceClassName` `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource`, use `net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbcx.JtdsDataSource` (also mentioned on [this page](https://github.com/tomekw/hikari-cp) which also indicates HikariCP was tested with the jTDS driver).

(*) The options available for the `SQLServerDataSource` are documented in [ISQLServerDataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff427247%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) but I could not find any options for statement caching.

(**) Encouraging comment in one of the last [bug-reports](http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/bugs/729/): "We are using jTDS 1.3.1 with SQL Server 2014 with no issues."

Comment: It's been a while, but I have used jTDS in the past with great success.

Comment: Unfortunately jtds is only jdbc3 compatible.